# End of stream reached when InputStream.read(array) does not return array.length?

Tags: java, sockets, byte, arrays, inputstream

I'm having these lines of code:

```
final int packetLength = 64 //just some constant
InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
byte[] packet = new byte[packetLength];
int read = in.read(packet, 0, packetLength)

if(read != packetLength) {
    //End of stream=
}
```

Can I be sure that if the `read(byte[], int, int)` does not return the same value as the length it should read, the stream has reached the end of stream?

Because the next `read()` call should return `-1` shouldn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't be sure of that. `InputStream` doesn't block until it's read all the data you've requested - it blocks until it's read *some* data. (The default implementation of `InputStream` *will* read until it's read everything it can, but there's no guarantee that subclass implementations will do so.)

You should read until the `read` call returns -1 - or if you just want to read exactly `packetLength` bytes:

```
byte[] packet = new byte[packetLength];
int offset = 0;
while (offset < packetLength) {
    int bytesRead = in.read(packet, offset, packetLength - offset);
    if (bytesRead == -1) { 
        // Incomplete packet - handle however you want to
    }
    offset += bytesRead;
}
// Hooray - read the complete packet.
```

Comment: So let `in` in the example above be a SocketInputStream, I should call read(byte[], int, int) again and again and always append the data to a buffer until the read method finally returns -1 or packetLength bytes were read?

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock: If you're only interested in reading `packetLength` bytes, that's fine. If you want to read to the end of the stream, you need to keep reading until `read` returns -1.

Comment: I want to read `packetLength` bytes. But until now I handled it as end of stream if the bytes read were fewer than `packetLength`. So I don't want to read to the end of stream but I need to know if the end of stream has been reached.

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock: Right, I'll edit my answer then.

Comment: Thank you so much! That seems to be the solution for a really nasty problem I had.